# Android app video live stream with gps position

Tags: android, video, stream, gps, position

Does anyone know how to easy share **live video stream** from android together with map with gps position?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is:

1. use youtube live stream on android
2. use glympse app on android
3. share location with Glympse
4. copy youtube embeded iframe
5. create html file

```
<html>
<!-- paste iframe from youtube -->

<iframe id="glympser" width="600" height="500" src="https://www.glympse.com/ext/XXXXX" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</html>
```

6. replace XXXXX with your glympse code.
7. publish html file